# Programmatically get EWS accesstoken

Tags: android, token, exchangewebservices

I have a working EWS connection, but at the moment I have to fill in my username and password everytime that I stop the app. Eventually alot of different users will use the application. Is there a way to programmatically get an accesstoken which I can store in the localstorrage? (I don't want to save the password)

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
    service.setCredentials(credentials);

    service.setUrl(new URI("https://domain/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called **impersonation** (the mail server admin must run a power shell command to assign superuser privileges to a designated mail account).

Here is the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx

Also here is a working example of how I use impersonation for hundreds of users.
What you need is to store the usernames in a hashset or dictionary instead of an access token (there is no access token in EWS).

```
Private _ExchangeServicesMainThread As New Dictionary(Of String, ExchangeService)
Private _UserIdState As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Private _Connections As New Dictionary(Of String, StreamingSubscriptionConnection)
Private _Subscriptions As New Dictionary(Of String, StreamingSubscription)

Private Function InitializeService(pUsername As String) As ExchangeService
    Dim oExService As ExchangeService
    Dim strEmailAddress As String = pUsername & config.MailDomain
    Dim strAdminEmailAddress As String = config.ExchangeServerAdminUserName & config.MailDomain

        oExService = New ExchangeService(config.ExchangeVersion)
        oExService.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        oExService.Url = New Uri(config.SecureHTTP & config.EmailServer & config.ExchangeManagedAPIEndpoint)
        oExService.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(config.ExchangeServerAdminUserName, config.ExchangeServerAdminPass, config.ActiveDirectoryDomain)
        oExService.ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, strEmailAddress)

        Return oExService
End Function
```

Assuming you have an initialized dictionary of all the users then loop though your dictionary so that you assign an exchangeservice to each one of them and store this username/exchangeservice in a new dictionary

```
    For Each strUserName As String In _UserIdDictionary.Keys
        _ExchangeServicesMainThread.Add(strUserName, InitializeService(strUserName))
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To bad they don't have a accesstoken. I can't get access to the exchange as admin so this won't be an option for me. Stil it's helpful to know that there is no accesstoken.